# Shower makes loud squealing noise at lower settings

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure

I have an older three knob shower that make a ridiculously loud squealing noise along its pipes all the way down to the basement. It outputs water at a quite a high pressure and whenever I try to lower the hot/cold settings it starts squealing. Its more apparent on the hot knob so I have to leave it at high-max which ends up quickly depleting the hot water heater tank. Any suggestions on how to mitigate this?

Comment: Squealing could be caused by partially blocked ports in the shower head. A possible fix is to soak the shower head in CLR or equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by opening up the unit and replacing the bibb washers. When worn they can vibrate and cause unholy squeals.